# Reference ENUM description when building selectList for dropdown list control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a form view model class that populates Select Lists for use by my views. Below is an extract from a section that creates a SelectList. The problem is that its a lookup table containing 2 other keys

```
        var waterIndicatorValues = waterIndicator
            .OrderBy(u => u.WaterIndicatorDescription)
            .Select(u => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.WaterIndicatorId, u.WaterIndicatorDescription + " [" + u.UnitTypeId.ToString() + "] " + u.HazardTypeId.ToString()));
        this.WaterIndicatorList = new SelectList(waterIndicatorValues, "Key", "Value", water.WaterIndicatorId);
```

Instead of UnitTypeId and HazardTypeId I want the text descriptions associated with those Id's. So i'd like my code to look like this :

```
        var waterIndicatorValues = waterIndicator
            .OrderBy(u => u.WaterIndicatorDescription)
            .Select(u => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.WaterIndicatorId, u.WaterIndicatorDescription + " [" + u.UnitTypeId.ToDescription() + "] " + u.HazardTypeId.ToDescription()));
        this.WaterIndicatorList = new SelectList(waterIndicatorValues, "Key", "Value", water.WaterIndicatorId);
```

This code returns error "Method 'System.String ToDescription(System.Enum)' has no supported translation to SQL."

Any comments/help greatly appreciated

ENUM for UnitTypeId:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Emas.Model.Enumerations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the Unit Types.
    /// </summary>
    public enum UnitType
    {
        [Description("- Please Select -")]
        Blank = 0,

        [Description("kWh")]
        kWh = 1,

        [Description("m3")]
        m3 = 2,

        [Description("litres")]
        litres = 3,

        [Description("Kg")]
        Kg = 4,

        [Description("Unit(s)")]
        Unit = 5,

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use extension methods within LINQ that pulls data from the database as it cannot be convert this extension code into SQL. You can however use `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to trigger the database hit and then use your extension methods on the result in memory instead.

Update:

Based on what you're trying to achieve in your updated code, I think [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2008/03/31/use-the-descriptionattribute-with-an-enum-to-display-status-messages.aspx) may have the answer you need. You'll need to cast to the enum type too of course.

Update 2:

Converting into memory using `ToList()` before doing the select with extensions should work ok like below:

```
    var waterIndicatorValues = waterIndicator
        .OrderBy(u => u.WaterIndicatorDescription)
        .ToList()
        .Select(u => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.WaterIndicatorId, u.WaterIndicatorDescription + " [" + u.UnitTypeId.ToDescription() + "] " + u.HazardTypeId.ToDescription()));
    this.WaterIndicatorList = new SelectList(waterIndicatorValues, "Key", "Value", water.WaterIndicatorId);
```

Comment: Hi Chris something like ".Select(u => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.WaterIndicatorId, u.WaterIndicatorDescription)).ToList().Select(<something here>);" - can you give me a hint please, many thanks

Comment: If you can supply the code for the enum and database calls it may help put it in context so I can understand where you're going wrong better.

Comment: waterIndicator table is a lookup table containing the key and description and another 2 numeric keys that reference ENUMS. I'm trying to select the key and description as a value pair but I wanna cooncatenate the descriptions from the ENUM into the select list for the drop down. Hope this makes sense :-) CHEERS

Comment: I guess I can loop waterIndicator and update in memory but not very neat. I think it may be possible to do this on one statement

Comment: See my updated link above for a way to do this. Hope this works ok for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris but I already have this code. I use toDescription() all over the app to get ENUM descriptions. I'm just trying to neatly append the descriptions in memory outwith LINQ call

Comment: Updated to show code description doing `ToDescription()` in memeory after calling `ToList()`.

Comment: GOT IT, its easy (i used .AsEnumerable() in the expression:
            var wasteIndicatorValues = wasteIndicator
                .OrderBy(u => u.WasteIndicatorDescription).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(u => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(u.WasteIndicatorId, u.WasteIndicatorDescription.ToString() + " (" + u.UnitTypeId.ToDescription() + ") " + u.HazardTypeId.ToDescription()));

Comment: My way above should work too. Please vote and accept the answer if you believe it helped.